# How to unmark a field of the output model as required in the docs

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi

I am trying to familiarize myself with fastAPI. Currently I'm struggling with the tutorial https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#see-it-in-the-docs
I'm not able to mark a field of the output model as **not required** in the generated docs as described in the mentioned tutorial.

If I try out the exact same code from the tutorial:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr

app = FastAPI()

class BaseUser(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: EmailStr
    full_name: str | None = None

class UserIn(BaseUser):
    password: str

@app.post("/user/")
async def create_user(user: UserIn) -> BaseUser:
    return user
```

The field "full_name" of the output model is marked as required in the documentation. The same field of the input model is not marked as required in the doc. Does anybody have an explanation or could tell me how to mark fields of the output model as not required? I'm using python 3.11, fastAPI 0.103.0

Update:
The above code is part of the file main.py in which uvicorn is started with the app:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8000, host='127.0.0.1')
```

Comment: Where do you have the UserOut model defined in your code? Based on what you have in the question, you shouldn't even see a UserOut schema.

Comment: @DiegoL You are totally right, my response model is called "BaseUser" but nevertheless the field "full_name" of the output model is always marked as required in the doc.

Comment: Ok now I understand. Well, I have checked for myself and indeed "full_name" of the output model is marked as required, which should not happen. Could you use an old version while it is being corrected? For example, I am currently using 0.97.0 in production and it works correctly. Thank you for your question, it is something that we must solve.

Comment: @DiegoL I reverted to fastAPI 0.99.0, 0.100.0 and 0.102.0 and it works correctly. After that I tried 0.103.0 again and it works suprisngly also. Than I saw that a side effect of my tests with older versions of fatAPI was a older version of pydantic and pydantic-core. First I updated pydantic-core and it still works (optional fields are not marked as required). After updating pydantic to version 2.3 the described behaviour occurs. Hope that helps fixing the problem. Many thanks for your help.